# How to create an HTML button that acts likes a link?

Tags: html

Iam unable to find out the code which makes me to create button using html and that works as link.

I have tried from many sources but I'm unable to figure out my problem. So im hoping that anyone from this website will help me to sort my problem.

Comment: This is a repeated question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-do-i-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link

Answer (score -1):

To put inside the  of your HTML file

```
<form>
   <input type="button"onclick="window.location.href='https://stackoverflow.com';" value="stackoverflow" />
</form>
```